# Quotient of two quotient modules with some inclusions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose now $A, B, C, D$ are all $R$-modules with $B\subset A$, $C\subset A$, $D\subset C$, $D\subset B$, then I wonder how to show $$\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{\frac{C}{D}}=\frac{A}{({B+C})}.$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JustinYoung, could you kindly describe this map more precisely as an aswer? Thanks.

Comment: There is something wrong here, if you take $A=C=\mathbb Z$, $B=2\mathbb Z$ and $D=0$, then you can see that $C/D = \mathbb Z$ is not a submodule of $A/B = \mathbb Z/2$. You should correct the statement and then prove it with quotient maps.

Comment: @JustinYoung, thanks for your answer. So the correct statement is we must gurantee that $C/D$ is a submodule of $A/B$?

Comment: You could do that, my solution was to just define the cokernel of $C/D \to A/B$ and show that is isomorphic to $A/(B+C)$.

Comment: It should be clear that $D$ plays no role in the problem, to make this work cleanly, you should define $D=B\cap C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the short exact sequence $C/D \to A/B \to Q \to 0$ (this is to fix the problem in the comments). We will now show that $Q\cong A/(B+C)$. Consider the composition $A\to A/B \to Q$, clearly this composition sends $B$ to $0$, and we have a commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C @>>> A \\
@VVV @VVV\\
C/D @>>> A/B @>>> Q
\end{CD}
so the composition also sends $C$ to zero, so we get an induced map $A/(B+C) \to Q$.
Now consider the induced map $A/B \to A/(B+C)$, if we precompose $C/D \to A/B \to A/(B+C)$, then the composition is clearly zero, so we get an induced map $Q \to A/(B+C)$. Since both of these maps are induced by canonical quotients, it is very straightforward to check that they are inverses.

Comment: I wonder why "the composition also sends $C$ to zero"?

Comment: Could you kindly explain it ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you believe the diagram commutes? If so, it follows from exactness of the bottom row, the composition of two maps in an exact sequence is zero ($Q$ is defined as the cokernel of $C/D \to A/B$).